# Starcluster put - sync?

Tags: starcluster

I am using the starcluster command put to move files into my AWS cluster.
The problem is that if I add files to a directory and then want to upload it I need to either create a list of those files, or re-copy everything. I would like to to something similar to rsync. Is there a way to do it in StarCluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to my knowledge, no there is no sync command support in StarCluster at this time.

You can still do it without StarCluster. Find your node public DNS (can be found in AWS EC2 console) and use the certificate your cluster uses.

Also, if you have any python skills, I think it would be fairly easy to develop a command that does it. You are welcome to do it and contribute it back!